FCM onBackgroundMessage not working when the application terminated
i'm not able to make the FCM works on flutter when the application is terminated. I check other solutions provided in stack over flow but sit not working
FCM onBackgroundMessage doesn't work on terminated state
this is my code

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}


@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
      final iamge = await http.get(Uri.parse(message.data["image"]));
      await IosCommunicationNotification().showNotification(
              NotificationInfo(
                senderName: message.data["sender"],
                imageBytes: iamge.bodyBytes,
                value: message.data["body"],
                content: message.data["body"],
              ),
            );
}


BUT when I open the application the notification will appear :(
